# Google Script for scheduling pages on a Google Site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am exploring the option of using Google Sites for our new intranet. We need to be able to schedule pages when they are created to automatically be deleted on a particular day.

I know this functionality is not native, and I would like to know whether or not it's possible to write a Google Script for a scheduling gadget in the editor view (as opposed to the live site).

And advice is very welcome. Thanks!
Jessica

Answer (score 1):

If I was implementing this, I'd write a standalone script with two separate trigger functions, both of which run daily.

- Script 1 would inventory the pages in the site. When new pages are
  identified, their creation and projected deletion dates would be
  recorded.
- Script 2 would review the list of known pages, and delete any that
  have reached their expiry date.

The reason for splitting the work up is two-fold: it simplifies the problem a bit to think about it this way, and it reduces the chance of experiencing a script time-out failure.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a native way of doing this, I would create a WatiN interface to Google sites to create and delete pages

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't see any way for WatiN to integrate with the Google Site, since Google Sites are WYSIWYG editors only with no access to the back end.

Can you offer documentation for how they would integrate?

Comment: I got watiN to create WSIWYG posts on Wordpress through some fairly ugly javascript hacks. For example, you can update text in a tinyMce editor using javascript. You can also display the hidden forms to see if any of them contain the html to be saved and update them. Its all a very tricky way of doing it, and if anything on their site changes it'll probably break. But it should be possible.